# Space reduction in C

Tags: c

I have problem with a task that says 'rewrite the entered text and reduce multiple spaces to only one space'. The program i have written rewrites single words but completely stops working after i enter a single space.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t,c,state;
    state=1;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(c==' ') 
            state=0;
        if (state==0)
        {
            while(c=' ')
                state=0;
            putchar(' ');
            putchar(c);
            state=1;
        }
        else putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(c=' ')` shouldn't that be `while(c==' ')`? Also note that the body of this `while` statement is only the following `vstate=0;`.

Comment: Consistent indentation and turning on (And paying attention to!) compiler warnings would help a lot.

Comment: First you should [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) your code properly; this may seem unimportant to you, but it is very important. The more readable your code is the easier it is to debug. Then your inner  `while` loop is wrong (using `=` instead of `==`) and pointless because the only statement in this while loop is `state = 0;`.

Comment: Close voters: it's not only a typo, there is more wrong stuff

Comment: If you would have properly formatted your code, the error would have been clear immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You were trying to make a staet machine which basically is the correct approach, but you failed because there are two problems in these lines:

```
while(c=' ')
  state=0;
```

First you certainly wanted to write `while(c == ' ')`, and your compiler probably warned you about this.

But even this is wrong:

```
while(c == ' ')
  state=0;
```

This loop will never finish if the condition `c == ' '` is true.

What you need is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int c;
  int spaceread = 1;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c != ' ')
      spaceread = 0;   // something else than space => process normally
    else
    {
      // space char has been read

      if (spaceread)   // if a space has been read previously => do nothing,
        continue;      // just continue to read the next character.

      spaceread = 1;   // remember we've read a space
    }

    putchar(c);        // print character
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jabberwocky, now i understand that putting getchar in while doesnt work like i thought it would. As for the typo i am sorry for that inconvenience as i am very much still used to pascal and i will certainly move on to some serious program as online gdb didn't warn me about this.